# Proving continuity of a function in a real number line

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:ℝ →ℝ$ . Assume $f$ is increasing, i.e. $x<y$ implies $f(x)<f(y)$. Let $x_0∈ℝ$ also let f is continuous at $x_0$. Assume $f(x_0)$ is a cluster point of $f(ℝ)⋂[f(x_0),∞)$  and $f(x_0)$ is also a cluster point of $f(ℝ)⋂ (-∞,f(x_0)]$ .Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

In the problem above, I intend to prove that $x_0$ is continuous. My idea was to try and apply the three calculus rules of continuity but they seem not to work in this problem. How may I proceed?

Comment: $x_0$ is a point, it cannot be continuous.

Comment: @ZelosMalum I suspect the OP meant something like "$f$ is continuous at $x_0$".

Comment: Yes; f is continuous at x0

Comment: @Mike It is wrong only to confirm that in a comment. You should edit your question and repair it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\epsilon>0$ let $q\in f(\mathbb R)\cap[f(x_0),\infty)$ and let $p\in f(\mathbb R)\cap(-\infty,f(x_0)]$ such that $p<x_0<q$ and: $$f(x_0)-\epsilon<f(p)<f(x_0)<f(q)<f(x_0)+\epsilon$$

The existence of such $p,q$ is guaranteed by the fact that $f(x_0)$ is what you call a cluster point of the sets.

Then $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\subseteq(p,q)$ for $\delta>0$ small enough.

Consequently $|x_0-w|<\delta$ implies that $p<w<q$ so that: $$f(x_0)-\epsilon<f(p)<f(w)<f(q)<f(x_0)+\epsilon$$

This ensures that $|f(x_0)-f(w)|<\epsilon$.

By $\epsilon$,$\delta$ method it has now been proved that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: I now fully understand it courtesy of you @Vera. Thank you so much